# Can I change my public IPv6 by changing my MAC address?

Tags: networking, ipv6, mac-address

There is someone messing around my system and every connection he uses a different IPv6, but it's always from the same ISP, at first I thought that he would have hacked some machines, but it would be very much of coincidence have just machines from the same internet provider. So I think he is using some kind of MacChanger and the ISP is giving him a new IPv6 every time he gets connected.

Does anyone knows how it could be done?

Comment: This looks like this is off topic, but you can change your ip by unplugging your modem for a short period of time.

Comment: But yes, you can change your MAC address.

Comment: He may not be able to change IP by restarting router. This stuff depends on ISP, IP per MAC static behavior is not rare case.

Comment: Which Operating System are you using ?

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo I believe this guy is using Linux, I actually would like to know how would someone do it, doesn't matter the system, with this information I could think in a ways to mitigate it.

Comment: @Paulo : Linux does not generate random IPv6 addresses for outgoing connections, but Windows does. So I think the OS may be the source cause of the problem.

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo Thanks man! I'll more dig into this

Answer (score 0):

See if your router supports MAC address masquerading. If it is you can try setting this to emulate another MAC address. And, as a result, get another IP address by DHCP.